# How can I use Microsoft Word's spelling/grammar checker programmatically?

Tags: python, com, ms-word, word-2007, win32com

I want to process a medium to large number of text snippets using a spelling/grammar checker to get a *rough* approximation and ranking of their "quality."  Speed is not really of concern either, so I think the easiest way is to write a script that passes off the snippets to Microsoft Word (2007) and runs its spelling and grammar checker on them.

Is there a way to do this from a script (specifically, Python)?  What is a good resource for learning about controlling Word programmatically?

If not, I suppose I can try something from [Open Source Grammar Checker (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162220/open-source-grammar-checker).

### Update

In response to Chris' answer, is there at least a way to a) open a file (containing the snippet(s)), b) run a VBA script from inside Word that calls the spelling and grammar checker, and c) return some indication of the "score" of the snippet(s)?

### Update 2

I've added an answer which seems to work, but if anyone has other suggestions I'll keep this question open for some time.

Comment: The note at the bottom of the summary seems to indicate that this is not possible. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262605

Comment: Word's grammar checker leaves a lot to be desired.  Lots of false positives and false negatives.  Of course, I'm not aware of anything that's significantly better. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took some digging, but I think I found a useful solution.  Following the advice at http://www.nabble.com/Edit-a-Word-document-programmatically-td19974320.html I'm using the [win32com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module (if the SourceForge link doesn't work, according to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client) you can use `pip` to get the module), which allows access to Word's COM objects.  The following code demonstrates this nicely:

```
import win32com.client, os

wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
path = os.path.abspath('snippet.txt')

snippet = 'Jon Skeet lieks ponies.  I can haz reputashunz?  '
snippet += 'This is a correct sentence.'
file = open(path, 'w')
file.write(snippet)
file.close()

app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = app.Documents.Open(path)
print "Grammar: %d" % (doc.GrammaticalErrors.Count,)
print "Spelling: %d" % (doc.SpellingErrors.Count,)

app.Quit(wdDoNotSaveChanges)
```

which produces

```
Grammar: 2
Spelling: 3
```

which match the results when invoking the check manually from Word.

Comment: http://www.nabble.com/Edit-a-Word-document-programmatically-td19974320.html this link is not valid they may change domian or something else can you provide with new link of that site ??