# Get Incorrect Spelled words from microsoft word

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I have a text file having words that i need to validate.
After following the post :
[How can I use Microsoft Word's spelling/grammar checker programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646801/how-can-i-use-microsoft-words-spelling-grammar-checker-programmatically)

I used the Microsoft word for spell check.But i am unable to get the improper words from the word api using doc.SpellingErrors.Item(1).Name(as there is no Name attribute available).
So how can i retrieve words(in text) from the object returned by doc.SpellingErrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\temp\foo.doc")
if doc.SpellingErrors.Count:
    for err in doc.SpellingErrors:
        print err.Text
else:
    print "No errors"
word.Quit()
word = None
```