# Is there a PHP library for correcting grammar?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP library for processing strings and correcting grammar? I'm creating an application where the users are consistently inputting data without capitalizing letters etc.

Is there a library for processing this kind of thing, or am I better off just making it so that the first letter after every full stop is a capital and calling it a day?

Comment: do you want the first letter of each sentence capital

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162220/open-source-grammar-checker

Comment: Do you want to display the errors to the user - eg highlight issues or are you wanting to 'sliently' correct the issues server side?

Comment: @Rupesh Pawar No its not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Bruce - Apologies, I should have been more clear. Just silently make minor corrections that we assume will be correct in 99% of circumstances - things like capital letters after full stops or at the start of a paragraph/first sentence, spell correction that is applied only when the checker can be certain that it's correction is.. correct. If that makes sense. Silent grammatical/spell check that isn't too 'abrasive'. I'm probably asking too much, I might end up putting something together myself.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help anyone who walks in here..

[grammark php](https://github.com/markfullmer/grammark) is one of the PHP library to check grammar

Answer (score -3):

http://www.languagetool.org/

http://www.afterthedeadline.com/

Comment: Not really what the OP was asking as these are NOT PHP libraries.

Comment: Languagetool is an opensource library and can easily be used for this purpose

Comment: Rather than just linking to the tools - it would be useful if you could expand your answer to demostrate how the OP would integrate Languagetool into his set up.